# Esp8266 and HttpClient not working properly

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, http

I am working on a project to send data to an API. Here is my code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#define USE_SERIAL Serial

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

const char* key="***********";

void setup() {

    USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);
    USE_SERIAL.println();
    USE_SERIAL.println();
    USE_SERIAL.println();

    for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
        USE_SERIAL.flush();
        delay(1000);
    }

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFiMulti.addAP("******", "*********");

}
String data=" "; 
void loop() {
    data+="{";
    data+="\"";
    data+="light";
    data+="\"";
    data+=":";
    data+=830;
    data+=",";
    data+="\"";
    data+="temperature";
    data+="\"";
    data+=":";
    data+=23;
    data+=",";
    data+="\"";
    data+="humidity";
    data+="\"";
    data+=":";
    data+=202;
    data+="} ";

    // wait for WiFi connection
    if((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

        HTTPClient http;

        USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
        // configure traged server and url
        http.begin("https://us-central1-sensorapp-d2a64.cloudfunctions.net/getData",key);      //Specify request destination
        http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  //Specify content-type header
        int httpCode = http.POST(data);   //Send the request
        String payload = http.getString();                  //Get the response payload
        USE_SERIAL.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
        USE_SERIAL.println(payload);    //Print request response payload

        USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
        if(httpCode > 0) {
            // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

            // file found at server
            if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
                //   String payload = http.getString();
                USE_SERIAL.println(payload);
            }
        } else {
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
        }

        http.end();
    }

    delay(30000);
}
```

After one successful request, it gives `error 400 (Bad Request)` until I reset the nodemcu. But then again it sends the data once successfully and continues with `400 (Bad Request)`.

Why are all the following requests bad? Is there something I haven't done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare and initialize `data` as a `String` in the global space. Then, in loop, you use a bunch of concatenations to build your request string.

You never clear the contents of `data`, but back at the top of `loop()` on the next round, you concatenate all the string data again, which duplicates it.

Side note, the `String` type is terrible for low-memory devices, and especially bad when you use a lot of concatenations. Because of the way the [`String`](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/) type works internally, when you concatenate strings, you end up leaving "holes" in the RAM that aren't likely to be able to be re-used.

Even if you do fix the code by clearing `data` after you submit your HTTP request, your program will still run out of RAM pretty quickly.

Better would be to build the constant parts of the string as constant globals and just concatenate the variable parts when needed and clear it after use.

Best would be to stop using `String` and use instead a `char data[DATA_SIZE]` type of string buffer and use the standard C string utilities like `strncpy()`, `strnlen()`, `strncat()`, etc.

Comment: Thank You For the reply. I will do it and will update things.

Comment: Just using the statement data=" "; in the loop solved my problem.